# Structured-binding declaration of a range in range-v3

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3, structured-bindings

The c++2a working draft has the [`std::ranges::subrange`](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.subrange) utility, which enables ranges and views to be unpacked into an iterator and a sentinel; for example:

```
std::optional<int> foo(std::vector<int> const &v, std::size_t const n)
{
  auto [it, e] = std::ranges::subrange(v | std::ranges::view::drop(n));

  it = std::ranges::find_if(it, e, [](auto const i) { return i % 2 == 0; });
  if (it == e)
    return {};
  return {*it};
}
```

Is there a similar facility in range-v3?

Comment: v1.0-beta of range-v3 has [`subrange`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/v1.0-beta/include/range/v3/view/subrange.hpp) like in C++20. Older versions seem to have [`iterator_range` and `sized_iterator_range`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/iterator_range.hpp) with similar functionality but it's probably better to use v1.0-beta in order to be more consistent with the standard.

Comment: @cpplearner That's exactly what I needed. Thanks. I was using the version shipped with ubuntu 18.04 (I believe it is 0.4), but It's OK to upgrade. If you wish to post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: For the record. The example shown is wrong because the `subrange` is constructed from a temporary range. It should read `auto Rng = /* … */; auto [it, e] = subrange(Rng);`.

Comment: Is it a problem? I know the underlying container shouldn't be temporary, but is it a problem for ranges?

Comment: @CygnusX1 Yes, I think so. Luckily the ranges library is able to detect such dangling ranges and prevents incorrect code from even compiling: https://godbolt.org/z/gqd6n3. There may be cases, however, where it is safe to iterate a view whose lifetime has expired: [range.dangling](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.dangling).